# ionic app showing white screen when increase its sdk

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Ionic:

```
 Ionic CLI                     : 6.20.4 (C:\Users\ajinkyam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.13
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.10
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.3.10
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.10
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.5.1
```

Cordova:

```
 Cordova CLI       : 11.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 10.0.0, ios 5.0.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 16 other plugins)
```

Utility:

```
 Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\ajinkyam\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v10.15.3 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.4.1
   OS                : Windows 10
```

I am not able to debug the root cause of the issue.I am running the command
ionic cordova build android -- release
my debug apk is running fine but release apk is not working